# Joi - multiple `when` clauses

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

I have two validations to perform on the same payload:

When `hasSalary` is true, either `monthlySalary` or `annualSalary` must be present.

When `hasCosts` is true, either `monthlyCosts` or `annualCosts` must be present.

I have coded this as:

```
Joi.object({
  hasSalary: Joi.boolean(),
  monthlySalary: Joi.number(),
  annualSalary: Joi.number(),
  hasCosts: Joi.boolean(),
  monthlyCosts: Joi.number(),
  annualCosts: Joi.number(),
})
.when(
  Joi.object({ hasSalary: Joi.boolean().valid(true).required() }),
  {
    then: Joi.object().xor('monthlySalary', 'annualSalary')
  }
)
.when(
  Joi.object({ hasCosts: Joi.boolean().valid(true).required() }),
  {
    then: Joi.object().xor('monthlyCosts', 'annualCosts')
  }
);
```

This correctly gives a validation error for: `{ hasSalary: true }`:

```
message: '"value" must contain at least one of [monthlySalary, annualSalary]'
```

... and for `{ hasCosts: true }`:

```
message: '"value" must contain at least one of [monthlyCosts, annualCosts]'
```

... but doesn't work as I expected when both the booleans are `true`, and the second `when`'s constraints are not met:

```
{
  hasSalary: true,
  monthlySalary: 300,
  hasCosts: true,
}
```

I hoped for `"value" must contain at least one of [monthlyCosts, annualCosts]` here, but instead I got a clean validation with no error.

I think I understand what's happening - chaining `when`s is creating a series of guards, and the first matching one wins.

So what construct can I use in Joi (ideally version 15) to achieve what I wanted?

Comment: Just tried `object(...).when(cond1, schema1).concat(object(...).when(cond2, schema2))` and that fails tests in the same way.

Comment: Is the property `hasCosts` required? Is the property `hasSalary` required? Is a `false` value possible for these two properties?

Comment: Can a `monthlySalary` or `annualSalary` or `monthlyCosts` or `annualCosts` exists, even when `hasSalary` or `hasCosts` are false?

Comment: @a1300 I would be stripping `annualSalary` if `hasSalary` is false or absent, etc. I excluded the code for that, to keep the question minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the newest version `Joi` [17.2.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/Joi) you don't have this problem (multiple when conditions resolve correctly)

But with `Joi` [15.1.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/Joi) you can use the following workaround:

```js
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

const one = Joi.object({
  hasSalary: Joi.boolean().valid(true),
  monthlySalary: Joi.number(),
  annualSalary: Joi.number(),
}).xor('monthlySalary', 'annualSalary');

const two = Joi.object({
  hasSalary: Joi.boolean().valid(false),
  monthlySalary: Joi.number(),
  annualSalary: Joi.number(),
});

const three = Joi.object({
  hasCosts: Joi.boolean().valid(true),
  monthlyCosts: Joi.number(),
  annualCosts: Joi.number(),
}).xor('monthlyCosts', 'annualCosts');

const four = Joi.object({
  hasCosts: Joi.boolean().valid(false),
  monthlyCosts: Joi.number(),
  annualCosts: Joi.number(),
});

const one_three = one.concat(three);
const one_four = one.concat(four);
const two_three = two.concat(three);
const two_four = two.concat(four);

const schema = Joi.alternatives().try(
  one,
  two,
  three,
  four,

  one_three,
  one_four,
  two_three,
  two_four,
);
```

Run some tests:

```js
// works
const data1 = {
  hasSalary: true,
  monthlySalary: 2000,
};
console.log(schema.validate(data1).error);

// works
const data2 = {
  hasSalary: false,
};
console.log(schema.validate(data2).error);

// works
const data3 = {
  hasCosts: true,
  monthlyCosts: 300,
};
console.log(schema.validate(data3).error);

// works
const data4 = {
  hasCosts: false,
};
console.log(schema.validate(data4).error);

// works
const data5 = {
  hasSalary: true,
  monthlySalary: 2000,

  hasCosts: true,
  monthlyCosts: 300,
};
console.log(schema.validate(data5).error);

// works
const data6 = {
  hasSalary: false,

  hasCosts: true,
  monthlyCosts: 300,
};
console.log(schema.validate(data6).error);

// works
const data7 = {
  hasSalary: true,
  monthlySalary: 2000,

  hasCosts: false,
};
console.log(schema.validate(data7).error);

// works
const data8 = {
  hasSalary: false,

  hasCosts: false,
};
console.log(schema.validate(data8).error);

// error
const data9 = {
  hasSalary: true
};
console.log(schema.validate(data9).error.message)

// error
const data10 = {
  hasSalary: true,
  annualSalary: 1000,

  hasCosts: true,
};
console.log(schema.validate(data10).error.message)
```

Comment: Thank you. Just to confirm, all we're doing here is building every possible combination and making an `alternative` for each one? So if I added a third kind of element like this it would become 16 lines, etc. in a combinatorial explosion?

Comment: Correct. I know its not a pretty solution. But as long as you can't upgrade it works...